# Can't kill supervisord inside of docker container

Tags: linux, docker

I have docker container and it has `supervisord` inside.
I wish to `kill` that process

```
root         1  0.0  0.1  59768 13360 ?        Ss+  20:29   0:01 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/supervisord
```

I login

```
sudo docker exec -ti blahblah bash

root# kill -KILL 1
```

it does not kills process 1 but I can kill any another process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you kill the process the whole container would stop. So you might as well run.

```
docker stop containerName
```

or if you want to force it you can change stop to "kill" or "rm -f"(if you also want to remove the container)

Comment: So I can't kill process 1 if I wish container to continue running?

Comment: Exactly, if you do kill it the container will go down.